# How to decompile CHM file including project file

Tags: chm

By using:

`hh -decompile test sample.chm`

I get decompiled CHM files in test folder, together with toc and index files, but project file is missing, so I can't recreate the CHM file, without manually recreating project file.

Problem is that it's not single CHM file, and all these CHM files were autogenerated from source documentation, but CSS defining fonts uses unfortunate sans-serif font family which looks ugly in CHM rendered (IE) and my task is to correct this issue.

Does someone know of a tool that can extract also the project file from CHM, so I can finish this in a minute?

Comment: I doubt the project file would be included in the `.chm`.

Comment: Well, project file was used to generate CHM file, so I was hoping for it in decompiled folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract hhp file from a chm file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015894/how-to-extract-hhp-file-from-a-chm-file)

Answer (score 0):

I made quick batch script to generate project file.

**Disclaimer**: script assumes toc and index files share same name, and opening page is index.html

**Usage**: `hhp.bat toc-base-name`

```
@echo off
echo [OPTIONS] > %1.hhp
echo Binary TOC=No >> %1.hhp
echo Binary Index=No >> %1.hhp
echo Compiled file=%1.chm >> %1.hhp
echo Contents file=%1.hhc >> %1.hhp
echo Default Window=%1 >> %1.hhp
echo Default topic=index.html >> %1.hhp
echo Display compile progress=No >> %1.hhp
echo Full text search stop list file=%1.stp >> %1.hhp
echo Full-text search=Yes >> %1.hhp
echo Index file=%1.hhk >> %1.hhp
echo Language=0x409 >> %1.hhp
echo Title=%1 documentation >> %1.hhp
echo. >> %1.hhp
echo [WINDOWS] >> %1.hhp
echo %1="%1","%1.hhc","%1.hhk","index.html","index.html",,,,,0x63520,220,0x10384e,[0,0,1024,768],,,,,,,0 >> %1.hhp
echo. >> %1.hhp
echo [FILES] >> %1.hhp
dir/b/s/a-d  | findstr /vi ".hh .bat" >> %1.hhp
```

Comment: The script is very, very basic and doesn't even attempt to reconstruct the hhp file other than a oneliner that generates the filelist.

Comment: Well, euh, I didn't expect a batch script per se. But something that at least would preserve context, since many apps use that.

Comment: And what kind of context is not preserved, by this script?

Comment: the context-ids of a CHM. Usually a .h. These can be retrieved by e.g. the chmls extractalias command in recent Free Pascal distributions.

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware of that, nor my CHM files had context ids. Usually way of calling CHM for reference here, is by index keyword. Quick googling shows that also context ids can be trivially added through a batch script, if user detects such files. Lets hope that someone, who needs that feature extend this script, as this and similar questions are left without working solution elsewhere.

Comment: IF the .h is extacted. But contents can also be recovered to some form (though less perfect) if extended decompilation is off. Just not with a .bat :-)  The earlier named chmls has some of that.